# How to print success message in the client page from the server side using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jQuery Ajax to post the data and display the success message accordingly.
Below is the code :

**Javascript**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
</script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('form').submit(function(event) { //Trigger on form submit
                    $('#name + .throw_error').empty(); //Clear the messages first
                    $('#success').empty();

                    var postForm = { //Fetch form data
                        "name": $("#name").val(),
                        "element_4_1": $("#element_4_1").val(),
                        "element_4_2": $("#element_4_2").val(),
                        "element_4_3": $("#element_4_3").val(),
                        "email": $("#email").val(),
                        "input4": $("#input4").val(),
                    };

                    $.ajax({ //Process the form using $.ajax()
                        type        : 'POST', //Method type
                        url         : 'contact.php', //Your form processing file url
                        data        : postForm, //Forms name
                        dataType    : 'json',
                        success     : function(data) {
console.log("inside success3") ;
$("#stage").text(data);alert(data);

                        if (!data.success) { //If fails
                            if (data.errors) { //Returned if any error from process.php
                                $('.throw_error').fadeIn(1000).html(data.errors); //Throw relevant error
                                                         console.log("inside failure") ;
                            }
                        } else {
                                                        console.log("inside success") ;
                                $('#stage').fadeIn(1000).append('<p>' + data.posted + '</p>'); 
console.log("inside success2") ;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default submit
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post">


                        <h4 style="padding-top:8px;">Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked <font color="red">*</font></h4>
                            <label>Name<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
                            <input class="form-control" style="height:35px;width:230px;border-radius:4px;" required type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
                            <label>Phone<font color="red">*</font></label><br>


        <span>

            <input id="element_4_1" name="element_4_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value=""  type="text"> -

        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_2" name="element_4_2" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text"> -

        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_3" name="element_4_3" class="element text" size="10" maxlength="10" value=""  type="text" required >

        </span>

<br><br>
                            <label>Email<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
                            <input id="email" class="form-control" style="height:35px;width:230px;border-radius:4px;" required type="email" name="text"/><br>
                            <label for="input4">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="4" id="input4"></textarea>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <button type="submit" style="margin-left:65px;"class="btn btn-large btn-info" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**PHP Server Side**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
$errors = array(); 
    $form_data = array(); 
header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($form_data);

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=chop($_POST['element_4_1']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_2']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_3']);
$email=chop($_POST['email']);
$message1=chop($_POST['input4']);

if ($name && $phone && $email) { 

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: sales@test.com \n";
$recipient= "test@test.in";



$subject="Online Enquiry   ";


$message="\nName                   : $name\n";

 $message.="\nPhone                  : $phone\n";

 $message.="\nEmail ID               : $email\n";

 $message.="\nMessage                : $message1\n";


 //send auto-reply
$subject_reply="Thank you for contacting us";
$message_reply="Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.";
//mail($email, $subject_reply, $message_reply, $headers);



 //Send Mail
//===========
if(isset($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
error_log($message);
    $form_data['status'] = 'success';
error_log($form_data['status']);

} else {
    $form_data['status'] = 'error';
error_log($form_data['status']);

} 
}

?>
```

Now everything works fine, but I'm not able to send the success message from the server side to client side. How can I get the success message displayed in the client page. In the client side javascript when I print data in alert box I see an empty box. How can I pass the data variable from server side to client side.

Comment: @Abhishekkadadi It is outside the form

Comment: show your full Html file.

Comment: try $("#stage").html(data) instead $("#stage").text(data)

Comment: Nothing got displayed

Comment: you are displaying it in <div></div> right?

Comment: echo  $form_data['status'] = 'success'; from server side . it wil display on client

Comment: Yes I did it. It displays success. But I want it from Jquery Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo "<script>$('#id or .class').html('error or success message here ');</script>";
```

Comment: `"); $("#stage").text(data);alert(data); if (!data.success) { //If fails if (data.errors) { //Returned if any error from process.php $('.throw_error').fadeIn(1000).html(data.errors); //Throw relevant error console.log("inside failure") ; } } else { console.log("inside success") ; $('#stage').fadeIn(1000).append('

' + data.posted + '
'); console.log("inside success2") ; } } }); event.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default submit }); }); `- this got printed

Answer (score 0):

The output of the PHP (created using echo or print or similar) is the data you pass to your calling Javascript.

In your PHP code you create an emtpy `array()` in your variable `$form_data` and then you output this empty array using `echo json_encode($form_data)`. The result on client side will be an empty array, which is not surprising to me.

Bottom line: Everything you output in your PHP will end up as `data` in the success handler of your Ajax call.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. I have created an array out of $form_data. What are suggesting me to do

Comment: When I try to echo the $form_data I get success printed in logs

Comment: The only place you output `$form_data` in your code (to the console!) is right after you defined `$form_data` as an empty array. At that point `$form_data` will be output as being empty (of course).